# Custom Selenium Formatter - How do I get comments?

Tags: selenium, comments, formatter

I've been following this tutorial to write a custom selenium formatter: http://seleniumrecipes.com/content/adding-custom-formats.

Comments in a Selenium test script don't follow the general layout

```
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>6000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<!--This is a comment-->
```

But you still get a command as you loop through the commands in the testCase, but all the values are undefined.

```
var commands = testCase.commands;
for (var i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
    var command = commands[i];
    result += command.command + ',' + command.target + ',' + command.value + "\n";

}
return result;
```

I've briefly looked at the source and can't see anything.

Is there a way to get the comments from a Selenium script in a formatter?